# Emacs mouse-5 binding trouble (scroll down)

Tags: emacs

I added this to my config file to fix scrolling and add some trick for text scaling but mouse-5 and M-mouse-5 and C-mouse-5 doesn't work. I still can see messages : `<mouse-5>` is undefined, etc... Why it doesn't work for mouse-5? How can I bind mouse-5?

```
;; ===== Scrolling fix for advanced mouses =============================
(defun up-slightly () (interactive) (scroll-up 5))
(defun down-slightly () (interactive) (scroll-down 5))
(global-set-key [mouse-4] 'down-slightly)
(global-set-key [mouse-5] 'up-slightly)
; Scroll up five lines with META held
(global-set-key [M-mouse-4] 'down-slightly)
(global-set-key [M-mouse-5] 'up-slightly)
; Scroll up one line with SHIFT held
(defun up-one () (interactive) (scroll-up 1))
(defun down-one () (interactive) (scroll-down 1))
(global-set-key [S-mouse-4] 'down-one)
(global-set-key [S-mouse-5] 'up-one)
; Scroll up one page with CTRL held
;;(defun up-a-lot () (interactive) (scroll-up))
;;(defun down-a-lot () (interactive) (scroll-down))
;;(global-set-key [C-mouse-4] 'down-a-lot)
;;(global-set-key [C-mouse-5] 'up-a-lot)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") 'text-scale-increase)
```

> app-editors/emacs-23.3-r2  USE="X alsa dbus gif gpm gtk jpeg png sound
>   tiff xft xpm -Xaw3d (-aqua) -athena -gconf -gzip-el -hesiod -kerberos
>   -livecd -m17n-lib -motif -source -svg -toolkit-scroll-bars"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like using the `kbd` macro b/c you can just cut and paste the name of the key you get from using <kbd>C-h k</kbd>.  So try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-4>") 'down-slightly)
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-5>") 'up-slightly)
```

Comment: there is (global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-5>") 'text-scale-increase) but it even doesn't work and (global-set-key (kbd "<C-mouse-4>") 'text-scale-decrease) works fine.